# Issue with Rewriting an URL for Weblogic Server 10.3.6

Tags: linux, httpd, oracle, weblogic

I have been working on 2 different web servers(dev-banabc and dev-banxyz), on which we have 2 applications running on each Weblogic Server. I have tried other solutions found on serverfault, however, nothing is working for me as it only works for the domain only not for the exact URL.

URL of 1st Application:  http://dev-banabc.domain.com:7740/SBOX/twbkwbis.P_GenMenu?name=homepage

URL of 2nd Application: http://dev-banxyz.domain.com:9001/ssomanager/c/SSB  (This is configured for the SSO)

We don't want our users to access 1st URL because of security reasons and want them to redirect to 2nd URL whenever they try to do that.

I tried to configure it by below method in httpd.conf file on the server dev-banabc:

```
Listen 7740
<VirtualHost *:7740>
 Redirect / http://dev-banxyz.domain.com:9001/
 <IfModule ossl_module>
  SSLEngine off
 </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

However with this method, whenever I try to access http://dev-banabc.domain.com:7740/SBOX/twbkwbis.P_GenMenu?name=homepage, it redirects me to - http://dev-banxyz.domain.com:9001/SBOX/twbkwbis.P_GenMenu?name=homepage. I want it to go to the whole URL - http://dev-banxyz.domain.com:9001/ssomanager/c/SSB.

So it is picking up the values from the 1st URL after the slash. This is where I need a fix or any solution to set it up.

Also is it possible to have the redirection configured for 2 or 3 predefined URLs, not for all?

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Comment: the pattern is not clear, but it is certain you need a pattern, so RedirectMatch specifying a pattern would be more suitable for you perhaps. Show 2 or 3 examples of requests and where you want them to end up to show a clear pattern, and some may be able to help you.

Comment: We fixed it using a programmatic way instead of redirection of the whole URL.